# Mule EJB endpoint for dynamic method call

Tags: ejb, mule, esb, mule-studio

I am doing an integration poc to invoke a remote EJB servcie by ejb:connector and ejb:outbound-endpoint in component binding.

It works perfectly fine if I define methodArgumentTypes and method properties in ejb outbound endpoint

```
<flow name="ExternalServiceFlow" doc:name="ExternalServiceFlow">    
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="serviceInput" doc:name="VM"/>
    <ejb:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="weblogicEjbConnector" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String,com.fusa.ssg.datatype.Date,java.lang.String,com.fusa.ssg.datatype.AuditInfo" method="readAccountDetail" address="${external.ejb.service.address}"/>
</flow>
```

However, since I need to invoke other APIs in the same component binding, how can reuse the ExternalServiceFlow to invoke other methods besides readAccountDetail? I tried to remove the methodArgumentTypes and method properties, but the application started with exceptions

```
Element ejb:outbound-endpoint{address=${external.ejb.service.address}, connector-ref=weblogicEjbConnector, name=.ExternalServiceFlow:outbound-endpoint.32, protocol=ejb} must have all attributes for one of the sets: [ref] [method]
```

Please advise how I can reuse the same vm flow with different remote APIs call.

Comment: Have you tried with MEL expressions in the `method` and `methodArgumentTypes` attributes? Not sure if it works, as this is an old transport.

Comment: Hi, David, I am trying MEL expressions in the method, but how can I do for methodArgumentTypes? What i am doing now is using dynamic outbound-endpoint

<flow name="ExternalServiceFlow" doc:name="ExternalServiceFlow">    
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="serviceInput" doc:name="VM"/>
    <outbound-endpoint connector-ref="weblogicEjbConnector" address="${external.ejb.service.address}?method=readAccountDetail" />
</flow>

However, it throws exception if one parameter is Null which is supposed to map to a Date object. I need to know how to include in MEL.

Comment: I was thinking of trying `method="#[...MEL...]" methodArgumentTypes="#[...MEL...]"`.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried, hre is what I got.

<ejb:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="weblogicEjbConnector" address="${external.ejb.service.address}" method="#[header:SESSION:method]" methodArgumentTypes="#[header:SESSION:methodArgumentTypes]" />

Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: #[header:SESSION:methodArgumentTypes]
 at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:316)
 at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:212)
 at org.mule.transport.rmi.RmiConnector.stringsToClasses(RmiConnector.java:254)..... I did tried other scopes, same patterns of errors.

Comment: Yeah, expressions are not supported... it's really an old transport. Sorry, I can't help :'(

Comment: How tough if I extends ejb or rmi connector to support MEL?

Comment: Shouldn't be to bad: you can get the expression evaluation framework from the `MuleContext` and call it on the properties configured from the attributes.